# React component doesn't show correct render count

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a small example to show my problem.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const renderCount = ++useRef(0).current;
  const [, setValue] = useState(1);

  console.log("Render count", renderCount);

  const reRender = () => {
    setValue((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return <button onClick={reRender}>Render</button>;
}
```

[Show in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-leaf-m9db3?file=/src/App.js)

When I click the button 3 times the console output looks like this:

```
Render count  1
Render count  2
Render count  4
Render count  6
```

I would've expected the following:

```
Render count  1
Render count  2
Render count  3
```

Why doesn't it display each render count if it renders 6 times?
And why does it render 6 times instead of 3 times?

Comment: Please make your runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: ```import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [age, updateAge] = useState(0);

  console.log("Render count", age);

  const reRender = () => {
    updateAge((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return <button onClick={reRender}>Render</button>;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have used `useRef`. Above is simple example to make it work.

Comment: @maheshwaghmare - The OP's trying to track render counts, not state changes.

Comment: Oh! My bad. Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware about it.